# React Router - Problem with parameter that starts with slash

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a problem related to parameters passed within React Router (web). When the parameters contain a slash "/", I solved it by doing this:

```
<Route exact path="/admin/user/detail/:id+" render={[...]} />
```

so when a url similar to this "/admin/user/detail/gysyts/hjdjd"
is read the id parameter is set right "gysyts/hjdjd" (for example).

However, this approach does not solve the problem when the parameter starts with a slash, for example:
"/admin/user/details/**/eytgsheyeh**", the url becomes unusable because the id parameter is incorrectly valued.

Answer (score 0):

The `//` in uri is not a good practice, couldn't you just use a func to replace it with some other char(s) like `_` in React and back to `/` in backend?